# what will be third column of the given matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is the problem[image]

My attempt  : $\frac{1}{ \sqrt 2} x + 0.y +\frac{1}{\sqrt2}z =0,x+ z= 0, x=-z $  ,

And $\frac{-1}{\sqrt 3} x + \frac{-1}{\sqrt 3} y + \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}z= 0$, Now putting $x=-z$ we have $ \frac{-2}{\sqrt 3} x +\frac{-1}{\sqrt 3} y=0$ ,$-2x -y=0$, $x= -y/2$

Now i take  $x= c $, then   third column  will $ \begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ -1\\2 \end{bmatrix}$

Is  its true ?

Comment: Did you *test* if all columns are orthogonal? Btw, the *norm* of each column should be $1$ ...

Comment: @MartinR that  mean   i have  to take   $( -2 /  \sqrt 5 , -1 / \sqrt 5 , 2/ \sqrt5$

Comment: Is that orthogonal to the first two column vectors? – Again: You can easily check yourself if the answer is correct.

Comment: Have you heard of the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)? That provides an easy solution to your problem.

Comment: thanks  u @ Martin R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The column that you wrote is not orthogonal to the second of the given columns. A correct answer would be $\left(\frac1{\sqrt6},-\frac2{\sqrt6},-\frac1{\sqrt6}\right)^T$. Note that you'r after an *orthogonal* matrix.

Comment: Almost correct ... it should be a unit vector.

Comment: Yes. I had already noticed that. And, although that was not required, I chose the third vector so that the matrix belongs to $\mathrm{SO}(3,\mathbb R)$.

Comment: thanks u sir @JoséCarlosSantos  But how  u got  $\left(\frac1{\sqrt6},-\frac2{\sqrt6},-\frac1{\sqrt6}\right)^T$. ? can u elaborate more

Comment: You made an error in your computations. All I did was to solve the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\frac x{\sqrt2}+\frac z{\sqrt2}=0(\iff x+z=0)\\-\frac x{\sqrt3}-\frac y{\sqrt3}+\frac z{\sqrt3}=0(\iff -x-y+z=0).\end{array}\right.$$I got the solution $(-1,2,1)$ and then I divided it by its norm (so that I had a solution whose norm is $1$) and I multiplied it by $-1$ (so that the determinant of the matrix is $-1$, although, as I explained in my previous comment, this is not required).

Answer (score 1):

A matrix is orthogonal if its column vectors are pairwise orthogonal unit vectors. So your solution is wrong for two reasons:

- $(-2,-1, 2)^T$ is not orthogonal to the second column vector.
- $(-2,-1, 2)^T$ is not a unit vector.

In three dimensions this can be easily solved with the [*cross product:*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) $u \times v$ is a vector which is orthogonal to $u$ and  to $v$, and if both $u$ and $v$ are unit vectors then $u \times v$ is a unit vector as well.

So in your case the solution for the third column is the cross product of the first two columns:
$$
 \begin{pmatrix} \frac 1{\sqrt 2} \\ 0 \\ \frac 1{\sqrt 2} \end{pmatrix} \times
 \begin{pmatrix} -\frac 1{\sqrt 3} \\ -\frac 1{\sqrt 3} \\ \frac 1{\sqrt 3} \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \cdot \frac 1{\sqrt 3} - \frac 1{\sqrt 2}(-\frac 1{\sqrt 3}) \\
\frac 1{\sqrt 2} (-\frac 1{\sqrt 3}) - \frac 1{\sqrt 2}\frac 1{\sqrt 3} \\
\frac 1{\sqrt 2} (-\frac 1{\sqrt 3}) - 0 \cdot(- \frac 1{\sqrt 3})
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} \frac 1{\sqrt 6} \\ -\frac 2{\sqrt 6} \\ -\frac 1{\sqrt 6} \end{pmatrix} 
$$